# Accessing map of class A from class B

Tags: c++, class

I have two classes class A and class B. Class A has a map of type `map<int,int>`.

In class A, i have the following definition,

```
   typedef std::map<int, int> mymap;

    mymap MYMAP;

    A A_OBJ;

    // did some insert operations on A_OBJ's MYMAP
```

I also have the following function in class A that when invoked by B will return A's MYMAP as a copy to class B.

```
A::mymap A::get_port(){

   // Returns A's map
   return this -> MYMAP;

}
```

In class B,

```
void B::initialize_table(){

     A::mymap port_table = A_OBJ.get_port();

     cout<< "size of ports table at A is"<<port_table.size());

}
```

Code got compiled with out any issue. The only problem is that even if I insert some data to A's map, B always shows that A's map has 0 elements.

I have a timer at B which calls `initialize_table()` every 2s and it is supposed to get the latest copy of the map from A. Not sure where it went wrong.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Show us a full working program.

Comment: `A::mymap& port_table = A_OBJ.get_port();`

Comment: It's kind of hard to see what's wrong with your code since it doesn't compile currently. Consider posting an MVCE, because it currently sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: My STL is very rusty, but it looks to me like `A::mymap A::get_port()` is returning a **copy** of the map - because you are mapping int to int it will be a complete copy. You probably want to return a reference to the map so that when you update it from class B you update A's map and not a *copy of A's map*.

Comment: Hi Jimbo, I only need a copy. I'll not be updating it at class B.

Comment: Somthing is very odd here, since `A_OBJ` can't be a member of `A` as you claim. Please post some actual code and not an improvised approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that you're creating a copy of the `std::map`. The way to fix this is by initializing a reference to the map.

Consider the following stub:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using my_map = std::map<int, int>;

struct A {
  A() : m() {}
  my_map& get_my_map() { return m; }
  my_map m;
};

struct B {
  B() : a() {}  
  void initialize_map_ref();
  void initialize_map_val();
  void print_index_42() { std::cout << a.get_my_map()[42] << '\n'; }
  A a;
};

void B::initialize_map_ref() {
  // notice this is a reference
  my_map& m = a.get_my_map();
  m[42] = 43;
}

void B::initialize_map_val() {
  // notice this is a copy
  my_map m = a.get_my_map();
  m[42] = 43;
}

int main() {
    B b;
    b.initialize_map_ref();
    b.print_index_42();
    return 0;
}
```

`B::initialize_map_ref` initializes a reference (i.e., a reference to the map within `a`), where `B::initialize_map_val` creates a copy and initializes the copy. The copy dies after the call, so outside of the call, `m[42] == 0`. The reference initialization, on the other hand, persists because you've changed a reference to the underlying object.

Ideone: [With reference](http://ideone.com/XJCxog) and [with value](http://ideone.com/kORvDA).

Comment: Thanks erip! Finally figured it out. I was accessing a new object instead of the one that was already there. Had to use pointers.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I suggest returning by an R-value reference for the sake of efficiency (i.e. `A::mymap&& A::get_port(){return A::mymap(this -> MYMAP;) };`).</s>

I can only see your code failing in one of two circumstances:

- you are updating `A_OBJ.MYMAP` after you call `A_OBJ.get_port()`
  This will cause the copy to be out of date.
- or you are updating `A_OBJ.get_port()`. and then calling `A_OBJ.get_port()` again. This will cause the copy to be modified but the original map, to be left unmodified, resulting in the second call to `A_OBJ.get_port()` to not consider any changes made to the value returned by the previous.

Depending on what you want you may want to return a (const) reference to the map.

**EDIT** I mistakenly originally thought that `A::mymap port_table = A_OBJ.get_port();` would cause two copies, but now I realize it will cause a copy and then a move, it would also do that in the rvalue case, however that is likely to introduce undefined behaviour (I think) because of returning a reference to a temporary... (originally I had it `return this -> MYMAP` but would be an error as it would try to bind an lvalue (`this -> MYMAP`) to an rvalue reference)

Comment: As far as I know, a normal lvalue reference will be _as_ efficient as a rvalue reference without necessitating move semantics for the class.

Comment: Also, OP clearly doesn't want a `const` reference since OP is trying to _initialize_ a map.

Comment: @erip actualy OP clearly said that `A::get_port` returns a copy, so I assumed that's what he wanted. He also didn't state where or how he wants to initialise the map (It probably should be in A's constructor)